# Should I quit PhD after 4 years?

Tags: phd, journals, quitting

I am at the end of my fourth-year in the Ph.D. program at an average university and I am trying to decide if it's the right decision to leave without getting Ph.D. degree. I have an M.Sc. degree and it's ABD. Although I published many conference papers, I didn't publish a journal. One reason is that I worked a lot for many projects as the lead research assistant. Other reason is that my motivation to work on these journals keeps decreasing. I am making very small progress and I always feel very bad about it. I feel like I will never be able to finish these papers. Quitting will give me relief but it also means that I wasted at least two years of my life. Also, I don't want to regret this.
My relationship with my supervisor is not good. Working with him made me really depressed. I lost all my self-confidence. I sought professional counseling but it doesn't help much. Also, my partner is graduating next semester and needs to leave and find a job. I don't need a Ph.D. to get a job. I've already got many job offers. I don't want to work in academia.

Comment: What do you have left to do in order to complete it?

Answer (score 3):

Think of being a PhD student as a job.  If you think there’s another job you’d prefer, then switch jobs.  It’s no more of a waste than spending two years at another job that you end up leaving.

That said if you already have some substantial work finished you might ask your advisor if you can just graduate this year with a weak thesis.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Last year I was about to leave Ph.D. because I found a job. He convinced me that I will graduate if I write a couple of journals. He said that he'll help me and try to make my job easier. However, it didn't work like that. I just want to submit them asap and if the reviewers ask for additions or changes, we'll do them then. The papers are already very long and good as is. However, he doesn't accept anything other than perfect. Changes in the papers never end.

Comment: Perfection may work to your benefit, actually. It would be far worse if your advisor were ignoring you.

Answer (score 1):

Just because you did not complete is not a guarantee that 2 years were wasted - those job offers are probably based on that very experience.

Who knows, you may be able to put the Phd on hold, do some work and then come back and finish it.

Even changing institution could be the game changer as mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Transferring to another university will probably require a lot of work. I may need to start from the beginning with a new research topic. They will probably ask me to take more courses or retake the doctoral qualification exam.

Comment: @atticus 2 answers of 3 suggest changing institution as a possibility - your choice to make.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't list any positive aspects for continuing, I suspect that you have already made up your mind. However, it would be worth listing all of the positives and negatives so you have a balanced view. Try to weight the importance of each factor, both positive and negative.

But, if you and  your partner are probably moving, perhaps you can continue at a different university with a more compatible advisor. That might make a difference.

You also don't mention your field. In CS, conference papers are highly valued, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The positive aspect is getting the degree after working for it for so many years. My field is EE.

Comment: But you have to want the degree for something. A diploma on the wall has little value in itself. But look inward for the answers.